# SSL error SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in C++ application

Tags: c++, networking, ssl, openssl

in my c++ application I'm using open ssl in my networking functions.
I saw that immediately after I'm connecting to a socket succefully, I'm getting an error in my receive function that use SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYS_CALL. 
accoring to SSL documetation that's what it means:

> Some I/O error occurred. The OpenSSL error queue may contain more information on the error. If the error queue is empty (i.e. ERR_get_error() returns 0), ret can be used to find out more about the error: If ret == 0, an EOF was observed that violates the protocol. If ret == -1, the underlying BIO reported an I/O error (for socket I/O on Unix systems, consult errno for details).

in my case, ERR_get_error() returns 0 and ret == 0. this means that "

> an EOF was observed that violates the protocol.

do you know what does it means? I don;t understand. what do I need to check or to do in order to fix this issue?

thanks

Comment: Generally when reading from a socket, if the return value is zero it means that the connection has been closed by the other end. Check what happens on the other side of the connection.

Comment: If the peer gracefully disconnects, OpenSSL reports an `SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN` error.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from Remy is correct but let me clarify and extend that a bit.

The situation when `SSL_do_handshake()`, `SSL_connect()`, `SSL_accept()`, `SSL_write()`, `SSL_read()` or `SSL_shutdown()` returns 0, following call to `SSL_get_error()` returns `SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL` and an actual `errno` is 0 means that the peer closed TCP connection e.g. by calling `close()` without proper SSL shutdown.
It is a completely normal and common situation, yet it is not a graceful disconnection in terms of TLS/SSL. And for that reason, it is EOF that violates SSL protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Call `BIO_eof(SSL_get_rbio(SSL *)))`

It will return `1` if you received an unexpected `EOF`.

Here's an implementation of it:

```
switch(errorCode){
  ...
  case SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL:{
    if(BIO_eof(SSL_get_rbio(ssl){
      //Handle the EOF
    }
    //You have an other error, call ERR_error_string
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It means you connected to a peer socket that is not using SSL on its end.  It is not enough to just `connect()` the socket and start calling `SSL_read()` right away. You have to call `SSL_connect()` after `connect()` to perform an SSL handshake before you can then use `SSL_read()` and `SSL_write()`. Also, make sure you are connecting to the correct port. Some servers use separate ports for SSL and non-SSL connections.

Comment: -1. It means the peer disconnected unexpectedly, period. There is no evidence here that this is a plaintext peer.